# How to check user permissions against what is actually shown in a menu (represents pages to open))

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Scenario:

There are multiple users with different permissions which represented as an enabled menu option (when clicked it'll open a dialog or a new page to do some action). This is all shown as menu options and depending on user its either enabled or disabled.

Very simplified example:

Admin has following permissions >> create file, add to file, modify file, delete file, add folder, modify folder, delete folder;

Support has following permissions >> Create file, add to file, modify file, delete file, add folder, modify folder. Do not have delete folder;

User has following permissions >> add to file, modify file; Can not do the rest;

Super has following permissions >> Create file, add to file, modify file, add folder, modify folder. Can not delete neither file nor folder

How represent above in C#?

I've tried to do something like this:

```
class Perms
{
   string option {get; init;} // name of the action like "Create File" in menu
   bool used {get; init;} // Does this user has permissions to above "option"
   bool enabled {get; set;} // If "used" above is true then this may be enabled or not depending on user conditions 
}
public class Admin
{
  perms CreateFile = new perms { option = "Create File", used = true, enabled = true}
  perms AddToFile = new perms { option = "AddToFile", used = true, enabled = true}
  etc.....
}
.
.    // Other users
.
.
public class User
{
  perms CreateFile = new perms { option = "Create File", used = false, enabled = false}
  perms AddToFile = new perms { option = "AddToFile", used = true, enabled = true}
  etc.....
}
```

So for each user program will get the menu options actually displayed and check against each user class above.

Is there a better way to do this in C#?

Using above as a selenium test to check if the logged in user has the correct menu items enabled

If not clear enough let me know and I'll clarify the question.